# HTML Email Conversion for MVC4 C# Web Projects

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-email

I am currently working on an MVC4 C# Project within Visual Studio 2012. We recently added a system that sends out emails to our users. The system uses the MailMessage Class to format the message that is sent through the SmtpClient Class. This message has the property to be html to enable some visual formatting of the body text.

The issue is that the property message.Body is currently written into a single string which makes the code look very ugly and quite difficult to actually format. I did some research and notices that some solutions had the email as a separate HTML file that was linked into the system. This allowed for much simpler formatting of the message. Only issue is that the examples I found lacked documentation on how to properly implement this type of solution so I wondering if anyone could point me to some information or possibly provide an example.

Here is what I mean by ugly MailMessage code.

```
        var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        message.Subject = "Password Recovery Email";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body =
        "Hello " + UserName +
        "<br />" +
        "Greetings from website," +
        "<br />" +
        "You have requested a Password reset. To continue click the following:" +
        "<br />" +
        "http://www.website.com/PasswordRecover?passwordToken=" + passwordToken +
        "<br />" +
        "This link will expire in 5 hours." +
        "<br />" +
        "If you did not intend to request a password reset, you can ignore this email. Someone may have entered your information by mistake. Contact us at support@website.com for more assistance." + 
        "<br />" +
        "Cheers";
```

Summary:

- message.Body has ugly code and is difficult to format
- interested in a better solution
- please direct me to an article or an example

Comment: Put you email template in a partial view, give it a model, ur good to go http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/). It worked like a charm for me.